# No sound after 5 minutes

Tags: laptop, audio, windows-10, troubleshooting, lenovo-laptop

I play a video and the sound stops working after 5 minutes. 
I launch a game and sound stops working after 5 minutes.

Restarting the Windows Audio service via services.msc re-enables sound for another 5 minutes, then I loose sound again.

Testing the playback sound device in sound options returns "Error! Failed to play test tone."

I am using a Lenovo U330 notebook.

I found articles dating back to older versions of Windows with similar problems, but I have yet found a permanent fix that resolves the issue.

I used sfc/scannow in cmd and it returned errors that it can't fix , but the error log is huge and I can't pinpoint the issue.

How can I permanently fix my sound issues?

Comment: Can you use a stopwatch and time how long it takes? Is it exactly after 5 minutes or does the time vary? if so what is the minimum and maximum time? What time is it on your clock when it fails?

Comment: [How to make sense of the cbs log deatails and SFC](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/928228)

Comment: Did you try updating your sound driver?

Comment: I started watching a video in chrome and sound stopped at 6 minutes 20ish seconds. Video won't replay atm probably due to the virus scan running in background so can't give you a more accurate number immediately.

Comment: @Moab The four corrupted files are four Windows ribbon start menu icons according to the log. So that is probably a dead end.

Comment: I would update the sound driver if there is one available from the manufacturer.

Comment: @Moab downloading now, love the fact that sound drivers have 277 MB :/

Comment: Usually because it is a package that covers more than just your hardware.

Comment: @Moab installing realtek HD sound drivers seemed to have worked, but my sound quality is terrible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Installing Realtek HD Audio codecs solved the issue.](http://218.210.127.131/downloads/downloadsCheck.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=14&PFid=24&Level=4&Conn=3&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false)

My sound quality was reduced, still looking into the issue.

Comment: Use only one sound driver software corresponding to your laptop support/compatibility. Having two driver software installed could cause this problem.